# SQL Server parent-child relationship

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

I have a database table with a structure as:

```
Node       Parent
-----------------
T0         NULL
T1         T2
T2         T3
T3         T4
T4         NULL
T5         NULL
T6         T7
T7         NULL
T8         NULL
T9         NULL
```

NULL in *Parent* column means that node doesn't have any parent. For a given node which would be the best way to select all nodes that are somehow related.

For example if the given node is T8 the select should get just this node because there is no other relation to this node.

If the given node is T2 then the select should get T1,T2,T3,T4.

Comment: Have you tried to formulate a `SELECT` query for this? Do you have any SQL that didn't work?

Comment: Did you try a recursive cte? (search for "recursive cte parent child")